# Is there a way to turn a pandas dataframe into a widget where you can click a row and it store the ID associated with that row?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, dashboard, ipywidgets

I am currently trying to build a dashboard with Jupyter notebooks and Viola and I want the dashboard to contain the main dataframe as a clickable widget where you can select a row and it stores the row ID that will be used to update other portions of the dashboard.

I Initially got the idea from a a O'rielly Jupytercon video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i40d8-Hu4vM&t=1084s). The issue im running into is that i cant import a package they use which contains the DataGrid function.

I am unable to locate any documentation and/or import the package.

The following import is:

```
from bqwidgets import DataGrid
```

The inputs used for the notebook are seen at 16:40 of the video
The code used to develop the df that begins the widget process is at 18:56

I am hoping someone might be able to help me either figure out how to obtain this bqwidgets package OR provide me a different solution on to how to create a clickable df within a dashboard that stores the ID of row click and uses it for other components in the dashboard.

[image of dashboard idea in video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m891M.jpg)

Comment: I believe the bqwidgets / bqextra library was never open-sourced, it was a bloomberg internal only project.

You can use qgrid as an interactive dataframe, but not sure if it fulfills all your interactive needs.

Answer (score 0):

bqwidgets are a Bloomberg-only package that is only available in their BQuant product. Only their bqplot and bqviz are available publicly.